# Calling code behind method from Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, client-side

Apparently it is a very simple problem. I have a button on an ASPX page:

```
<input id="ok" type="button" name="ok" value="OK">
```

When this button is clicked, I want to call a method in code behind and do a postback afterwords.

What I have found so far is using `__doPostback` etc. but also came to know that Microsoft is moving away from it. Maybe `ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference` can work too but I am not sure how it can be done.

I cannot use an AJAX call from jQuery because of some restrictions.

Comment: are you not able to use a regular asp:Button?

Comment: Ummm... the button is generated by XML sent from database. I can send a complete <asp:button... tag from there. But how the button event will be tied to button?

Comment: do you build the button in code behind?

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. Unfortunately I could not describe my exact scenario completely as there were some limitations forced by the application. I have upvoted your answers and closing my question as it cannot be useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

You can use in you aspx markup:

```
<input id="ok" runat="server" onserverclick="btnOk_ServerClick" type="button" name="ok" value="OK">
```

and put this code in aspx code behind(.cs) file:

```
 protected void btnOk_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
}
```

Comment: Yes, I started to think on these lines too.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `runat="server"` tag on this input then you can access it on code behind

**Update**: if you wanna call a method look at this samples. [this](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View7B75C93E-C8C9-4576-972B-2C3138DFC671.htm) and [this](http://brian.dobberteen.com/code/calling-a-pagemethod-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively call an [http handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You could also implement a web service of some kind, either [REST](http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api) or [SOAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302125.aspx).

Each of the above could be called using a javascript event (for example [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)) registered on the specific html button, out of ASP.NET page lifecycle. For example you could call this function on the onclick event (`targetURL` would be replaced by the URL of http handler, or the respective service):

```
<button onclick="httpGetRequest('targetURL')">Click me</button>

function httpGetRequest(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to generate asp:button then it will be easy for you . You can add event handler to you button generated dynamically. ie)

```
btnClick.OnClick += new EventHandler(btnClick_Click);


Protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code goes here
}
```